# Apply function to a specific element of tuples in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of tuples and would like to modify (using a function) a specific element of each tuple in the list.

```
lst = [('a', 'b', 'c32@', 45), ('e', 'f', 'g812', 22)]
```

Ideally, my function should extract number from the text in [2] and return the list but with the third element modified.

So far I have tried using map and lambda together which only returns a list of the extracted number. Here is my attempt:

```
def extract_num(txt):
    # do sth
    return num

new_lst = list(map(lambda el: extract_num(el[2]), lst))
```

Note: I cannot modify the extract_num func to take a tuple as argument since it is used somewhere else without a tuple.

Comment: `new_lst = [extract_num(el[2]) for el in lst]` ?

Comment: There is one *ideal* output and one *correct* output. Could you please clarify what are you after?

Comment: @norok2 You are right. My implementation does not return the output I am after, i.e., the original list but with the only the third element of each tuple modified. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using another function the whole modification logic that uses your `extract_num` function?

```
def extract_num(txt):
    return 'x'

def alter_tuple(t, pos=2):
    return t[:pos]+(extract_num(t[pos]),)+t[pos+1:]

new_lst = [alter_tuple(t) for t in lst]

print(new_lst)
```

output: `[('a', 'b', 'x', 45), ('e', 'f', 'x', 22)]`

Comment: Apparently the output is *ideal* but not *correct* :-D

Comment: @norok2 ? I don't know what is the expected output, depends on what `extract_num` is doing ;)

Comment: The question says that yours is sort of *ideal* output, but later on it says that the `list(map())` code gives the *correct* output. The issue is with the question, not with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean it?

```py
def trim(sentence):
    return int(''.join([str(element) for element in sentence if element.isnumeric()]))

print(trim('sdf2dsfd54fsdf'))
>>> 254
print(list(map(lambda el: trim(el[2]), lst)))
>>> [32, 812]
```